# General solution presented in x(y)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution for: $y'=\frac{x^2}{6y+cos(y)}$

Determine the integration constant using initial condition y(-2)=0
Present the particular solution subject to this initial condition in the explicit form (think in which form the explicit solution can be presented y(x) or x(y).

Not sure I'm interpreting this correctly, but I find the implicit solution:

$3y^2+sin(y)=\frac{x^3}{3}+C$

And then find the integration constant:

$C=-\frac{4}{3}$

Finally, present the explicit solution:

$x(y)=\sqrt[3]{9y^2+3sin(y)+4}$

Comment: Are you asking us to verify your work?

Comment: No, I was asking if I was interpreting the question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3y^2+sin(y)=\frac{x^3}{3}+C$

On putting $x = -2$ and $y = 0$ in above equation,

$0 = \frac {-8}{3} + c$

$c = \frac 83$

Now put $c$ in above equation. You get answer.

Comment: Yep, I was using $x^2$ instead of $x^3$

Comment: Any other doubt you have?